# Vue 2: Set empty class as data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a scenario in Vue 2 where I am initializing API classes as data properties on my component like so:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#my-element'
  data: {
    apiUrl: apiUrl,
    api: new ApiClient(this.apiUrl)
  }
})
```

API Client:

```js
class ApiClient {
  constructor(apiUrl) {
    this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
  }

  async getRequest() {
    // Perform GET
  }
}
```

This works just fine, but I have scenarios where I need to use two different API clients. If a certain `prop` gets passed into my component, I want to initialize that data property as `secondApi`, as an example.

In this scenario, I see myself using the `created()` hook:

```js
created() {
  if (prop === true) {
    this.secondApi = new SecondApiClient(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

In my `data : { }` object though, I'm not sure how to initialize this optional `secondApi` property properly (in the case that the prop is not passed in). Do I just set it as an empty object at first? It will always be a `class` object like `apiClient`. Is there an empty class data type?

Comment: is it like 
`created() {
  if (prop === true) {
    this.secondApi = new SecondApiClient(this.apiUrl);
  } else this.firstApi = new firstApiClient(this.apiUrl);
}
`
????

Comment: Good question. No, I will always initialize the first API class. The second API class is the only one I want to (try) to initialize conditionally.

Comment: I would simply intialize it to false, and make the prop not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can follow one of the below

**Approach 1:**

```
data() {
 return {
  apiUrl: apiUrl,
  api: null // or you can even keep it as new ApiClient(this.apiUrl) if that's the default value
 }
},
props: ['certainProperty'],
created() {
  if (this.certainProperty === true) { // certainProperty is a prop
    this.api = new SecondApiClient(this.apiUrl);
  } else this.api = new ApiClient(this.apiUrl);
}
```

Sometimes there might be a delay in receiving the props so its better to follow the below approach

**Approach 2:**

```
data() {
 return {
  apiUrl: apiUrl,
  api: null // or you can even keep it as new ApiClient(this.apiUrl) if that's the default value
 }
},
props: ['certainProperty'],
watch: {
 certainProperty(newVal) {
  if (newVal === true) { // certainProperty is a prop
    this.api = new SecondApiClient(this.apiUrl);
  } else this.api = new ApiClient(this.apiUrl);
 }
}
```

**Note:** You need to pass the props from parent component like

```
<child-component :certainProperty="true" />
```